# Looping through XDocument and getting values of child nodes

Tags: c#, xml

Here's what my XML file looks like.

```
<PictureBoxes>
  <P14040105>
    <SizeWidth>100</SizeWidth>
    <SizeHeight>114</SizeHeight>
    <locationX>235</locationX>
    <locationY>141</locationY>
  </P14040105>
  <P13100105>
    <SizeWidth>100</SizeWidth>
    <SizeHeight>114</SizeHeight>
    <locationX>580</locationX>
    <locationY>274</locationY>
  </P13100105>
</PictureBoxes>
```

What I'm actually trying to do is loop through each control in my form and save the Size and Location property on an XML file. The `<P...`> Node is actually the name of my picturebox and I need to use that name as well.

After creating the XML, I want to try creating the picture boxes on the form again using the XML file. So what I need is get the name of the `<P...>` node and the values of the child nodes.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Well, nothing, first time trying XML and what I found searching seems to be for when I know the name of the parent node, in this case I don't. I need to get the values under `<P14040105> ` and `<P131000105>` but I don't know those node names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the [FormLoad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload(v=vs.110).aspx) and [FormClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37d8kw11(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to load and respectively save data from/into the xml file.

In your `FormLoad` method loop through the child elements of `PictureBoxes` element and for each element create a `PictureBox` and set it's values from the xml data as shown below:

```
protected override OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    var doc = XDocument.Load("path/to/xml/file");
    foreach(var element in doc.Descendant("PictureBoxes").Elements())
    {
        var pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Name = element.Name.LocalName;
        pb.Size.Width = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("SizeWidth").Value));
        // other properties here
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
    }
}
```

And in `FormClosing` do the reverse thing - iterate over picture boxes and save the properties in xml:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    var doc = new XDocument();
    doc.Add(new XElement("PictureBoxes", 
        this.Controls.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
            .Select(pb => new XElement(pb.Name,
                new XElement("SizeWidth", pb.Size.Width),
                new XElement("location", pb.Location.X)))));
    doc.Save("path/to/xml/file");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the name of the parent node? the `<P...>` nodes.

Comment: nvm, I got it. It's `element.Name.LocalName`